# Microsoft Graph add Secondary Smtp

Tags: c#, .net, email, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am currently struggling with the graph behaviour. I want to add a secondary mail to the a azure ad user. So naturally I used the OtherMails attribute of the user:

```
var mails = new List<string>()
mails.Add("myaliasmail@domain.com")
var updatedUser = new User
{
    OtherMails = mails,
};
UpdateUser(updatedUser);
```

The other mails are added to the user in azure. But the proxy addresses are not updated. And so you cant receive any mails on the account

I cant edit the ProxyAddresses directly because it's readonly. Apparently it is working if you change the Mail attribute (Changes to this property will also update the user's proxyAddresses collection).

But why are the proxy addresses not updated if the OtherMails attribut is changed.

Is there even a way to add secondary mails through the graph api? Or do I really need to fallback to remote powershell and connect to the azure exchange to apply my changes?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from Vasil Michev at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/516697/add-secondary-email-with-graph.html

Currently there is no way to add a secondary mail through graph. So I have to fallback to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps